# element.remove() and element.append() conflicting with each other

Tags: append, appendchild, removechild

I am writing a chess game in JavaScript/React.

When I drag the white piece to the black piece, I am trying to remove the black piece and append the white one, like this :

```
function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    //Set the background to original color on droping the piece:
    ev.target.style.backgroundColor = ev.target.dataset.squarecolor
    //Save moving piece data into an object:
    let movingPiece = JSON.parse(ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text"))
    if (movingPiece.color === 'white' && ev.target?.dataset?.color === 'black' && ev.target.nodeName === 'IMG') 
    {
      ev.target.remove()
      ev.target.append(document.getElementById(movingPiece.id)); 
    }
  }
```

So:

1. Remove black piece
2. Add white piece

But I end up with 0 pieces on the screen. Not sure if this is because of render or JS is removing the newly appended item.

**Reproducible example:**

https://codesandbox.io/s/chess-app-11qvk9?file=/src/components/pieces.jsx

Comment: I found that the issue is that I'am trying to append to the element that I have just removed. What I , actually need to do , is to append to the parent of that element!

Answer (score 0):

No need to remove

```
function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    //Set the background to original color on droping the piece:
    ev.target.style.backgroundColor = ev.target.dataset.squarecolor
    //Save moving piece data into an object:
    let movingPiece = JSON.parse(ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text"))
    if (movingPiece.color === 'white') 
    {
      //ev.target.remove()
      ev.target.append(document.getElementById(movingPiece.id)); 
    }
  }
```